Passing an argument from one Twilio function to another
I have a standard Twilio function:
exports.handler = (context, event, callback) => 
{
  const calledNumber = event.CalledNumber;
  if(calledNumber == "+18008675309") 
  { 
   const TheFunction = Runtime.getFunctions()['CheckForDessert'].path;
   const Function = require(TheFunction)
   var AvailableToDial = Function.CheckBusinessHours({"dessert":"yes"})
  }
  
  ...
}

The CheckForDessert function:
exports.CheckBusinessHours = function(context, event, callback) {
  console.log(event)

  return 'blankText'
};

How can I get the CheckForDesserts function to access the data passed to it, namely the fact that the key, 'dessert,' is set to 'yes?'
I've tried sending strings, JSON, etc., but I'm missing something because console.log inside the CheckForDessert function just gives me "undefined". Thank you!

the helper function (CheckBusinessHours) will not have context,event and callback as it is helper function. Replace it with the param that you want to pass.
Ref link below
Twilio docs

I realized that after a good night's sleep and sure enough, you were spot on. The helper function doesn't get called like a normal external call to a Twilio function, so it's just a normal function.
I'm curious, when I try to call the function using axios so that I can execute the function synchronously, I keep getting a 403 error. I cannot find anywhere in the Twilio docs where it talks about calling another Twilio function from a Twilio function with authorization, and setting the helper to private and/or public does not work. any idea how to do it?
